# Ruby // Getting Variables to Communicate Across Classes // Why nil?

Tags: ruby, class, inheritance

I have the following two classes I fabricated for simplicity.  I would like to take the information given in the first class, and use it in other classes throughout the program.  However, I can not seem to get the variable to retain it's value given by the user.

```
class Input
  attr_accessor :input

  def initialize
    @input = input
  end

  def call
    get_input
    # Changer.new.change(@input)
    output
  end

  def get_input
    puts "please write a number"
    @input = gets.chomp.to_s
  end

  def output
    p Changer.new.change(@input)
  end

end

class Changer < Input

  def change(input)
    if @input == "one"
      @input = "1"
    elsif @input == "two"
      @input = "2"
    elsif @input == nil
      "it's nil"
    else
      "something else"
    end
  end

end

Input.new.call
```

I have tried a few variations on the above classes, some with inheritance, some without, initializing, or not, etc.  They all seem to output 'nil'.  Please advise.  Thank you for your time.

Comment: When the `change` method in `Changer` runs, `@input` is an instance variable specific to that `Changer` instance, and _it is_ `nil`.

Comment: You should remove the inheritance: `Changer` is a class of its own, not a specialized `Input`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the change method in `Changer` runs, `@input` is an instance variable specific to that `Changer` instance, and it is nil.

You want your `change` method to work on the `input` argument being provided to it, rather than `@input`.

```
  def change(input)
    if input == "one"
      "1"
    elsif input == "two"
      "2"
    elsif input == nil
      "it's nil"
    else
      "something else"
    end
  end
```

Or better yet:

```
  def change(input)
    case input
      when "one"
        "1"
      when "two"
        "2"
      when nil
        "it's nil"
      else
        "something else"
    end
  end
```